# Не получается сохранить данные в pickle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Привет. У меня есть алгоритм, результат работы которого нужно сохранить и передать другому человеку. Я хочу это делать с помощью pickle на python 3.5. Проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке данных, они пропадают.

Приведу схему моих действий:

```
# Задаю параметры

clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clope, f)
```

После выполнения этого кода, оказывается, что `data/CLOPE_users.pickle` весит 75 байт. Хорошо, тогда я напишу скрипт, который будет загружать этот файл (вдруг, он, действительно, весит настолько мало, хотя оценочный вес должен быть определённо больше). Разумеется, после загрузки в новом скрипте, я увидел пустую структуру `clope`. Выглядит эта структура примерно так:

```
# Класс, описывающий работу с данными
class CData:
    # Список кластеров
    Clasters = [] # CClaster
    # Количество добавленных транзакций
    CountTransactions = 0
    # Словарь. Ключи -- номер транзакции. Значение -- номер кластера
    Transaction = {}
    # Номер итерации
    Iteration = 0
```

Пустая, правда, она не совсем. Например, данные в `Transactions` не сохраняются (они мне нужны больше всего). А вот переменные вида `CountTransactions` остаются и после загрузки.

Для порядку, я также приведу пример загрузчика:

```
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    clope = pickle.load(f)
```

Для того, чтобы как-то разобраться с ситуацией, я попытался поотлаживать прогу. О, чудо, все данные сохраняются и загружаются. Но!!! При одном условии. Все сохранения и загрузки должны выполняться в рамках работы одного и того же скрипта. Т.е. если скрипт завершить, то загрузить сохранённые данные не удастся и будет наблюдаться картина, описанная мной выше. Привожу пример, как я это делаю:

```
clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clope, f)
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    clopeLoad = pickle.load(f)
```

После загрузки в `clopeLoad` будут лежать все данные целыми.

Идём дальше.

В силу того, что в python всё передаётся ссылками, то я решил скопировать объект clope, прежде чем отправлять на запись. Но это тоже не помогло:

```
clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(copy.deepcopy(clope), f)
```

При загрузке в новом скрипте, все данные опять же исчезают.

Были мысли, связанные с тем, что нужно явно закрыть файл. Но это тоже ничего не поменяло. Т.е. :

```
clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clope, f)
f.close()
```

Сохранение данных руками тоже не работает:

```
clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Transaction[0] = 1
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(clope, f)

with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    clopeLoad = pickle.load(f)
```

При загрузке структура также остаётся пустой.

Далее начинается абсолютная магия. Допустим, я сохранил структуру, как это указывал выше. После этого запущу код:

```
with open('data/CLOPE_users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    clopeLoad = pickle.load(f)

clope = CLOPE.CData()
clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)
print("Finish")
```

В таком случае, сразу после загрузки данных, оказывается, что структура пустая. Но после выполнения `clope.Init(dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory)` и `clope`, и `clopeLoad` обратают все данные.

В связи с этим, я полагаю, что pickle каким-либо образом неявно сохраняет ссылки на объекты и при загрузке, они остаются. Но, что с этим делать я совершенно не понимаю. Подскажите, как мне сохранить данные при помощи pickle?

P.s. Такие проблемы, судя по всему возникают только в python3. Подобного рода казусов в python2.7 никогда не было. К сожалению, писать на python2.7 нет возможности, поскольку исходные данные хранятся в pickle и записаны именно в python3. Если нужна конкретика, то все исходные коды можно посмотреть тут: [CLOPE](https://bitbucket.org/egorsteam/clope)

Comment: в конструкции `with` файл сам будет закрыт. Лучше приведите минимальный пример с проблемой, чтобы желающие могли запустить его и проверить у себя.

Comment: @gil9red Так чем не нравится репозиторий и пример c 
`clope.Transaction[0] = 1`? Насчёт вашего комментария про `with`, я прекрасно понимаю. Но ситуация, в которой не понимаешь, как и что происходит, заставляет делать очень очень странные вещи.

Comment: тем что мне (и многим другим) лениво идти на другие сайты, искать там ваш полный код с заполненными данными, потом скорее всего качать его или через `git clone` или через вебморду в виде архива. Так же лениво и читать ваши размышления :) Лучше сразу -- пример с проблемой и жалоба на него :) Перед тем как я вам ответил, я набросал код с pickle, который сохраняет в файл и считывает, причем в двух разных запусках: https://gist.github.com/gil9red/83e18ffe600bc81447d7d118ce3c1b93

Comment: Что такое dataGroups, iter, repulsion, isSaveHistory? Как, по-вашему, мы должны воспроизвести ваш код без этих переменных?

Comment: Python 3 здесь не при чём. Это поведение pickle с подобного рода классами и оно ровно такое же в Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я нашёл вашу ошибку.

Вы абсолютно непитонично реализовали класс СData. В питоне все переменные, которые должны принадлежать самому экземпляру объекта, следует объявлять в специальной функции инициализации, которая всегда называется `__init__`. Обязательно с двойными подчёркиваниями в начале и в конце, и обязательно с маленькой буквы. После этого экземпляр объекта будет инициализироваться сразу при создании, вот так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.param1 = var1
        self.param2 = var2

obj = A('раз', 'два')
```

В этом коде аттрибуты param1 и param2 принадлежат самому объекту. Когда вы выполняете pickle они будут сохранены.

Вы же определяете ваши переменные не в инициализаторе, а просто в классе:

```
class CData:
    # Список кластеров
    Clasters = [] # CClaster
    # Количество добавленных транзакций
    CountTransactions = 0
    # Словарь. Ключи -- номер транзакции. Значение -- номер кластера
    Transaction = {}
    # Номер итерации
    Iteration = 0
```

К созданным таким образом переменным объект сможет обращаться как к своим, через `self.имя_переменной`, в том числе и менять их, но они хранятся не в `__dict__` самого объекта, а в `__dict__` класса.

Поэтому в пределах того же скрипта объект, восстановленный из pickle-дампа видел их наполненное состояние - ведь состояние класса после того как было заполнено данными, таким и осталось.

Однако в другом скрипте класс заново создавался с исходным пустым состоянием, и объект (который у вас сам этих данных не хранит) обращался к девственно чистому классу.

Выход: перепишите класс так, чтобы параметры объекта хранились в самом объекте.

Comment: Что такое `__dict__`?

Comment: @hedgehogues, это специальный атрибут, в котором хранятся переменные и методы объекта или класса (хотя на самом деле, класс - это тоже объект).